# Update a token in a json file using gradle task

Tags: json, gradle, replace, build, build.gradle

I want to update a token in my json file with some string like build number.

Build tool is gradle

What is the gradle task that can update a token in the json file before copying it ?

Comment: have you done any research? there are plenty different solutions to this. the easiest is to just to read and amend it groovy/java style. Try JsonSlurper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the gradle copy task with groovy templating inside your file such as ${version}

https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files